# StackOverFlow Error For Problem Number 50 in Leetcode

Tags: java

For the below Input I am getting a StackOverflow error. Can u guys help me with an explanation and how to solve this problem in my code.

```
 System.out.println(myPow(0.00001,2147483647));  

 public static double myPow(double x, int n) {
         
        return helperPow(x,n,1);
        }


     
     private static double helperPow(double x, int n,double d) {
         if(n == 0) {
             return d;
         }
         
         if(n < 0) {
             return  helperPow(x,++n, d/x);
         }
         
         return helperPow(x, --n, d*x); 
         
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your current approach, the number of levels of recursion will be equal to `n`, so it will definitely cause a [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29279234/9690075) exception as it requires considerable stack space.

Note that if `n` is an even number, `x^n` = `(x ^ (n/2))` * `(x ^ (n/2))`.

If `n` is an odd number, `x^n` = `(x ^ (n/2))` * `(x ^ (n/2))` * `x`.

So you can reduce the number of levels of recursion to `log(n)`, which will definitely not cause a `Stackoverflow` exception even if `n` is large (In your case, `n` is `2147483647`, it will take 31 recursions):

```
    public double myPow(double x, int n) {
        return n >= 0 ? helperPow(x, n) : 1.0 / helperPow(x, -n);
    }
    public double helperPow(double x, long n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1.0;
        }
        double y = helperPow(x, n / 2);
        return n % 2 == 0 ? y * y : y * y * x;
    }
```